# PersistValues for MongoDB Keys in Yesod/Persistent 2

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-persistent

I have some code that was doing the following in `persistent < 2`:

`(either (\_ -> 0) id).fromPersistValue.unKey.entityKey $ myEntity`

How can I achieve the same functionality using `persistent > 2` as `keys` are now defined by individual Backends and as such there is no `unKey` function? Is there still away to achieve these "Int representations" for MongoDB keys in newer versions of Persistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a [`keyToOid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-mongoDB-2.1.2.2/docs/Database-Persist-MongoDB.html#v:keyToOid) function that does approximately what you want in `Database.Persist.MongoDB`. From the [Persistent docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.1.4/docs/Database-Persist-Class.html#t:ToBackendKey), I gather the change was part of a move towards abstracting keys from backends:

> `class (PersistEntity record, PersistEntityBackend record ~ backend, PersistStore backend) => ToBackendKey backend record where`
>
> `ToBackendKey` converts a `PersistEntity Key` into a `BackendKey` This can be used by each backend to convert between a `Key` and a plain Haskell type.